# File writing and appending in Binary mode not working

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I am trying to append into file in binary mode but the logic below is not working.
For Pdf files,file is getting corrupted and for text files, it is adding some junk data in addition to my file contents.
My variable `m_strReceivedMessage` is of type `std::string`.

```
std::ofstream out(file, std::ios::binary | std::ios_base::app );
int i = sizeof(m_strReceivedMessage);
if (out.is_open()) {
    // out.write(m_strReceivedMessage.c_str(), m_strReceivedMessage.size());
    //out << m_strReceivedMessage;
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&m_strReceivedMessage), m_strReceivedMessage.size());
}
```

Comment: Try `out.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&m_strReceivedMessage.data()), m_strReceivedMessage.size());`

Comment: What was wrong with your first commented-out version? Or your second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the memory of the `std::string` object, rather than the character buffer that it contains. To get a pointer to the character buffer, see the [data()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) member function. Hint: The fact that you need to cast `std::string*` using `reinterpret_cast<char*>` is a dead giveaway that you're doing something very wrong.

Also, I'm not familiar with the PDF spec, but I suspect that it may possibly contain nul bytes. And depending on how you get your `std::string`, it's possible you may have missed any content after the first nul. `std::vector<char>` would be more appropriate way to store binary data.